# Node.js - JSON.parse - Add Nodes to the Result

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, oop

If I parse a JSON object in Node.js like this

```
var datap = JSON.parse(data);
```

I get an hierarchical object (as visible in the debugger):

```
datap = object
    account1 = object
        name = "A"
        type = "1"
    account2 = object
        name = "B"
        type = "2"
```

Now I would like to add an account3 with a line like this

```
datap.append("account3")
```

and ofcourse after this

```
datap.account3.append({"name":"C", "type":"1"})
```

My Javascript knowledge is still limited, is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: You are looking for the `Array.prototype.push` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the json is parsed you can just use in as an Object:

```
var datap = JSON.parse(data);
datap.account3 = { name :"C", type :"1"};
```